# Como puedo estructurar un proyecto con una primera carga de datos? Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-storage

Tengo un proyecto Expo/React Native el cual debo cargar datos iniciales desde firebase los cuales son principalmente Banners de publicidad, Estados, Ciudades y otros datos miscelaneos

Actualmente en el archivo inicial tengo una pantalla de carga donde llamo todos estos servicios pero esto esta demorando alrededor de 9 Segundos

Algun consejo?

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Gracias! es que no encontre otra forma de formular la pregunta